# How to share Amazon AWS credentials (S3, EC2, etc)?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, credentials

I have a personal Amazon account which I use to do a lot of shopping. I also recently linked this account to AWS. Now at work, some guys are doing experiments with Amazon using my account. How can I let them access the admin console, etc without giving them my Amazon credentials. I am not willing to share my Amazon shopping history or other things I use on Amazon, just the cloud services such as EC2 and S3.

What they need is access to the full admin console, and any monitoring tools on AWS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM)](http://aws.amazon.com/iam/).

> AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) enables you to securely
>   control access to AWS services and resources for your users. Using IAM
>   you can create and manage AWS users and groups and use permissions to
>   allow and deny their permissions to AWS resources